# how to notify client when each row are inserted during the bulk insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to notify or acknowledge to end user(client) when bulk insert perform. for Example - 8 rows are inserted out of 100.

Comment: It is very hard to give any suggestions here without seeing the code being used to bulk insert (it is not clear, for example, what you are bulk inserting **into**).

Comment: When did the bulk insert call return? After insertion is completed or Before insertion starts (insertion happens in a backgroud process)?